# Launch CUDA kernels sequence and data transfer between them

Tags: cuda

i have two kernel in same file, the code should run the first kernel to generate an array. then i need to send the generated array to the second kernel.
however, when i do this the second kernel see all the array elements are 0.

here is simplification (not a runnable code ) just a psyducode.

```
 cudaMalloc(device input array)
 cudaMalloc(result array)    
 cudaMemcpy(device_input_array,inputarray,size,hosttodevice)    
 kernel1<<<1,n>>(device_input_array,device_result_array)
 cudaMemcpy(host_result_array,device_result_array ... )     
 cudaMalloc(dev_secndarray)    
 kernel2<<<1,n>>>(dev_secndarray,device_result_array )
```

for testing.. in kernel2 i create a loop on device_result_array, how ever it prints all its elements as zero.

what is the proper way to send data between kernels. should i reserve space for the result array again ? what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory allocated through `cudaMalloc` exists till the end of application, or until you explicitly free the memory. Thus, the `device_result_array` can be passed directly to the second kernel as an input. I would recommend the following pattern:

```
cudaMalloc(device_input_array)
cudaMalloc(device_intermediate_result_array)
cudaMalloc(device_final_result_array)
cudaMemcpy(device_input_array,host_input_array,size,hosttodevice) 
kernel1<<<G,B>>>(device_input_array,device_intermediate_result_array)
kernel2<<<G,B>>>(device_intermediate_result_array,device_final_result_array)
cudaMemcpy(host_result_array,device_final_result_array,size,devicetohost)
```

If for some reason you actually need to make a copy of the intermediate result in the device, you have an option to call `cudaMemcpy(...,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice)`.

In either case, don't copy the intermediate result to host (unless you really need it for other reasons). Host<->Device copies are expensive.